# Android listView within tabwidget activity gives exception

Tags: android, listview, tabwidget

Using Google's "Hello TabWidget" tutorial found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html)  I was able to build a tabWidget layout, but I'm having a seriously difficult time trying to stick a listview within one of the tabs.

I've also read through a couple threads here about this issue, but they all pertain to assigning the ListView to the specific id "list", which I have done, but I still get a null pointer exception.

I have spent wayyyyyyy to much time on this elementary objective, so I've asked God for help, but I think he's busy right now.  Anyone on a lunch break?

**the activity in which the ListView is called**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;


public class SettingsActivity extends Activity  {
private ListView lv;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings);

    String[] settingsList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.settingsStringArray);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.id.TextView01, settingsList));

    lv.setOnItemClickListener
        (new OnItemClickListener() 
            {

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) 
                {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

**xml file from res/layout called within setContentView(R.layout.settings)**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ListView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/list">
</ListView>
<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `TextView01` needs to go into a separate XML file, say textview01. (The name needs to be lowercase, although the only error message you'll see about this will be in the console.) You would then access it as `R.layout.textview01`.

Comment: Thank you, Dan!  I don't know why I didn't catch that!!  I've been starring at this for 2 hours and couldn't see the writing on the wall.  Thank you very much, Sir!